# Element font-family is not allowed here anymore : Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I get the error mentioned in the title whenever I try to include a font in my XML.
Here's the XML code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".home_screen">

    <font-family>
        <font>

        </font>
    </font-family>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="HOME ACTIVATOR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I hover over the "font-family" tags, I see the issue pointed out by android studio. Documentation error maybe? 
I am following the online guide form the official google developers page here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource

Comment: It's seems that you didn't followed https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource as mention.

Comment: Yeah, I solved this issue just now. It was because I was not on a high enough API level (API 26.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved just now, looks like I was using API level 22 when  could only be used in API level 26.